# I have a planner tab on MS teams but I cant figure how to add the chat bot for it

Tags: bots, chat, microsoft-teams, microsoft-planner

MS Planner App in MS teams has "Bot" in it's description. Is this a Chat bot or is it a different bot kind and how do I add it to use it with my Teams app?

Searched MS support without success. There are multiple open tickets about it working/existing before. I do not see a "chat" tab when I open the planner app.

Comment: We don't have bot for planner app. You can add tabs to the planner app as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-configuring-builtin-tabs#planner-tabs).

Comment: Thank you, I will see into this.  I'd recommend removing the "bot" flair from the app description.